# Repetitive Use of Graphs in Multiple Worksheets For Excel(Using Macros)

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am trying to use Macros to write a code that would help me chart multiple graphs for the 122 worksheets I am working on right now.
The thing is each work sheet is exactly the same except the values that are to be graphed or changed. 
I have written the following code but im unable to apply it to multiple worksheets at a time, and macro results becomes specific to the worksheet it is in.
Please help

```
Sub ChartMacro()
'
' ChartMacro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
 Dim sSheetName As String

    sSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=27

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""China"""
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=('&sSheetName&'!$E$11)"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "='sSheetName'!$D$14:$E$14"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='sSheetName'!$E$20"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "='sSheetName'!$D$23:$E$23"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "='sSheetName'!$E$29"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "='sSheetName'!$D$32:$E$32"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "='sSheetName'!$E$38"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Name = "='sSheetName'!$D$41:$E$41"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = "='sSheetName'!$E$47"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Name = "='sSheetName'!$D$50:$E$50"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = "='sSheetName'!$E$56"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).Name = "='sSheetName'!$D$59:$E$59"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).Values = "='sSheetName'!$E$65"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).Name = "=""Singapore"""
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).Values = "='sSheetName'!$E$74"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(9).Name = "='sSheetName'!$D$77:$E$77"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(9).Values = "='sSheetName'!$E$83"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(9).XValues = "='sSheetName'!$A$3:$U$3"

    ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (3)
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlHigh
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Male-Female"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Male-Female"

    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With

    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoTrue
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With

    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd)
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine how to loop through every worksheet in your workbook? Ideally replacing `sSheetName` on each iteration?

Comment: Looping may not be necessary, but i'm looking for the ability to get a graph for whichever active worksheet i run the macro in.

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to generalize your code without seeing an example of the data, or knowing how you are unable to apply it to multiple worksheets.

Comment: I am not at liberty to show the data i am using. Sorry for that.
But is there any way i can use sSheetName as a variable that changes with active sheet , because the cell numbers remain the same for each sheet irrespective of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace `sSheetName` with just a `Worksheet` Object. Then you would need to alter your code just a tad to use those new objects.

```
Sub chartMacro()
'
' ChartMacro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Dim sheet as Worksheet
    Dim cht as Chart

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    Set cht = Charts.Add
    Set cht = cht.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=sheet.Name)

    cht.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

    cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""China"""
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheet.Cells(11,5)

    cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    cht.SeriesCollection(2).Name = Sheet.Range("$D$14:$E$14")
    cht.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Sheet.Range("$E$20")
    '...rest of sub follows...

End Sub
```

You could also clean up your code a bit by looping through `SeriesCollection` since it looks like your incrementing the `Sheet.Range()` by 9 rows each time.

Comment: The error still remains as a type error on cht=ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.

Comment: Great got the concept. It worked, Thanks alot for your assistance

Comment: @ayanbharadwaj check my edits where I change `Dim cht as Shape` to `Dim cht as Chart`. That should work much better since you will be dealing with methods specific to charts and not just shapes